# How to set different colors in each stacked bar chart cell?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

[image]

I am trying to create a chart like this. Below is my chart code. However, I am unable to set a different color in the second bar. The first color in the first bar gets set in the second bar.

```
self.chart = {
        type: 'horizontal-bar',
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            callbacks: {
              label: function (tooltipItem, _) {
                return $filter('number')(tooltipItem.xLabel);
              }
            }
          },
          events: ['click', 'mousemove'],
          hover: {
            onHover: function(item, chartElement) {
              item.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default'; 
            }
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                stacked: true,
                display: true,
                labelString: "Test"
              },
              ticks: {
                stacked: true,
                beginAtZero: true,
                maxRotation: 0,
                minRotation: 0,
                callback: function (value) {
                  return $filter('number')(value);
                }
              }
            }]
          }
        },
        data: [[2,12], [5]],
        labels: labels,
        colors: [chartBlue, chartGreen],
        datasetOverride: [{ stack: 1, fill: false }, { stack: 1, fill: false }]
      }
```

This is the result I am getting.

[image]

I need to set a different color (for example yellow) in the second bar.

Answer (score 0):

With `colors` you define the colors for datasets. With two colors you define two datasets. With your two arrays in `data` you have two datasets, that's why you can't see an additional color.
You need a third dataset for a third color, with `0` at the labels where you don't want a bar.

Check out the following example ([Working example at JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yakezejeha/1/edit?html,js,output)):

```
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      data: [0, 8, 4]      
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      backgroundColor: "red",
      data: [6, 2, 8],
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      data: [3, 0, 0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add more data?

```
 data: [[2,12], [5], [1], [4], [3]],
 labels: labels,
 colors: [chartBlue, chartGreen],
```

Try it and see what happens to the chart :)

Comment: more data(the data you provided) means the first bar gets stacked with different colors. I need to set a different color (for example yellow) in the second bar.

Comment: then add more colors at colors variable, as chartYellow. But i think that this will set the color as the third color when setting data, so to use the yellow color, you will need to set 3 values to see the yellow color.